# Google Sign-in & security shows unknown Linux under recently used devices

Tags: gmail, google-account, hacked

I signed into my Google account and see that there is this Linux that last synchronised recently under "recently used devices".

I have no clue what this is. I don't remember using any Linux or doing any syncing with my Google.

Is this likely a hacker?

Comment: Did you read the instructions under [Check for suspicious activity](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/3067630?p=devices&hl=en&rd=1)?

Comment: Had the same issue, figured out this Linux device is my SMARTtv, on which I have signed in or given access to my google Account, Via TV App on my Mobile. I made sure it is by checking the Mobile App install Date&Time on my Mobile vs. New Device signed in Date&Time (1st Sign in). MATCHES !!!

Comment: I've recently been concerned about this. If you're logged in to YouTube on a SkyQ box, this logs as a Linux machine with an image of a Laptop in your Google Account. I just kicked it out, logged it back in to YouTube and the same Linux machine reappeared.

Answer (score 3):

If you don't recognize an activity record in your account you should immediately change the account password.

From the below reference,

> If you believe your account has been compromised, please follow the
> steps to [secure your
> account](https://security.google.com/settings/security/secureaccount).

#### References

[Detecting suspicious activity on your account -Accounts Help](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/140921?hl=en)

Answer (score 3):

Follow these easy steps:

1. in footer you will see your IP address with a "details" link. Open the link and kill all other web sessions

   [image: killing sessions]
2. Change your password:
   [Changing Gmail password](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/41078)
3. Enable 2 step verification:
   [Gmail two step verification](https://www.google.com/landing/2step/)
4. Check all recovery options such as email and phone number